# Segmentation fault after trying to access a structure variable outside function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reference, parameter-passing

I have defined the structure variables are as follows;

```
typedef struct
{
    char   basename[33];        /* [C] Name of the 'Base' Node */
        int    Cell_Dimension;      /* [C] Cell Dimension */
    Parameters *BParam;
        int    Physical_Dimension;  /* [C] Physical Dimension */
        int    Number_of_zones;     /* [C] Number of 'Zone' nodes under the 'Base' node */
    int    flagTurbulence;      /* flag to store if its a turbulence problem 0-No / 1-Yes*/
    int    flagTurbModel;       /* flag to Store which turbulence model is to used 1->k-epsilon
                    2->k-omega etc*/
    int    flagConjugateHeat;   /* For conjugate heat transfer*/
    int    flagLES ;        /** LES is ON or OFF*/
    int    flagLESModel;        /** LES is static or dynamic */
    int    SolverScheme;
    LESdatastruct *LESdata;
        int    couplingTag; /* It hold information about the coupling of equations i.e. Coupled solver, semi-Coupled solver and Segregated solver. */
    int     Scheme;    /* It holds the information about Solution Algorithm to be used ie Implicit or semi implicit*/
    int     steadystate; /*It holds the information about if the problem is steady or unsteady...0-> Steady and 1-> Unsteady*/
    int     TimeStepingSchemeTag;
    Zone   *CgnsZone;       /* [C] 'Zone' Nodes under the Base Node */
    int     TotalVar;       //NEW ADDITION///
    int     VARTAG[30];     //NEW ADDITION///
    int     flagCTR;        /** to keep discretly energy conserving scheme ON, available only in LES */ 
    int     restart;
} Base;

/***********************Data Structure for METIS*************************************************************/
typedef struct
{
  idx_t ne;
  idx_t nn;
  idx_t nc;
  idx_t *eptr;
  idx_t *eind;
  idx_t *npart;
  idx_t *epart;
  int ncells;
  int nodes;
  int *elements;
  idx_t objval;
  idx_t nparts;
  idx_t ncommon;
  Base *MetisBase;
} METIS;
```

I have defined a function named NewEleConn() with following structure;

```
int NewEleConn(Root CgnsRoot,Root Metis,Base *MetisBase){
     MetisBase=(Base*)malloc(1*sizeof(Base));
     MetisBase->Cell_Dimension=10;
return 0;
}
```

In main function I have done the following;

```
    int main(){
METIS metisdata;
     ..
    ..
      CgnsRoot = ReadCgnsFile(filename1); 
      Metis=conversion(CgnsRoot);        
      NewEleConn(CgnsRoot,Metis,metisdata.MetisBase);
      printf("%d",metisdata.MetisBase->Cell_Dimension);
    }
```

At printing line of main function, it is giving me segmentation fault error for accessing the structure variable even though I have allocated memory inside the function.

Comment: when asking about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: regarding: `MetisBase=(Base*)malloc(1*sizeof(Base));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing the cast.  2) multiplying the function parameter by 1 has absolutely not effect.  Suggest removing the `1*`  (cont)

Comment: (cont) 3) when calling any of the heap allocation functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "your error message" )` so both your message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function

```
int NewEleConn(Root CgnsRoot,Root Metis,Base *MetisBase){
     MetisBase=(Base*)malloc(1*sizeof(Base));
     MetisBase->Cell_Dimension=10;
return 0;
}
```

deals with a copy of the original pointer. The function parameter `MetisBase` is a local variable of the function. Any changes of the variable within the function do not influemce on the original object.

You have to pass the pointer by reference. For example

```
int NewEleConn(Root CgnsRoot,Root Metis,Base **MetisBase){
     *MetisBase=(Base*)malloc(1*sizeof(Base));
     ( *MetisBase )->Cell_Dimension=10;
return 0;
}
```

And call the function like

```
NewEleConn(CgnsRoot,Metis, &metisdata.MetisBase);
```

Comment: Okay, I agree with you and suppose the MetisBase has 4 base structure inside it then how can I access any base structure variable corresponding to each component of MetisBase. For e.g., if MetisBase has four components the how to do  something like (MetisBase+1)->Cell_Dimension inside NewEleConn?